# My website is showing some kind strange ads without my permission

Tags: web

First of all i am sorry to ask such a stupid question. I have a website i.e. www.assameseonline.com. It is showing some kind of ads. Since I've cleared all data from my site and and deleted everything. Still this add is being displayed. The index.php page is completely blank. Please help.

Comment: Your host must be putting up those ads :p P.S I dont see anything

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.htaccess` file ... Usually at the bottom.   If it's not there, check with your web host to see if there was an `.htaccess` file uploaded above root level ...  I'll put money on that's the culprit